# pyramid wtforms label and error message translation(for i18n)

Tags: python, pyramid, wtforms

How can we translate the form label and error message of wtforms while using with pyramid.

Sample form:

```
class RegistrationForm(Form):
   name = TextField(_(u'Name'), [v.Required(_(u'Please provide your name'))])
   age = IntegerField(
    _(u'Age'),
    [v.NumberRange(min=12, message=_(u'Must be at least %(min)d years old.'))]
   )
```

After this i have done:

1. message strings extractions
2. translation of the strings in .po file
3. compiled to create .mo file

I am using jinja2 templates, the translation strings of jinja2 template are working fine, But the form elements translation are not working. Any idea on this, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems might come from the fact that `_` is called at import-time and not runtime, when the translation is not configured yet. It should not be a problem if you're using `pyramid.i18n.TranslationString`, because it is lazy, and only translated when displayed, but if you're using something else, that might be your problem.

So, how did you define `_` ?